# How to dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I have a PC with Windows 8 on it, but I would like to install Ubuntu on it. I have created a USB Drive with Ubuntu on it using Pendrive Linux's USB Creator as it was recommended by one of the guides on ubuntu.com. It's the 64-bit version of Ubuntu 12.10.

The question now is how do I dual-boot it. The PC came pre-installed with Windows 8 on it, so there is no normal BIOS order that i can configure or change. How to I do it?

Please help me and explain in an easy to understand way, I am a complete newbie when it comes to computers!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the proposed question.

Answer (score 1):

check out this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system). I had followed this link to install Ubuntu on a pre installed win8 system. Hope it helps!!! :)